# Adding border-right like to a SVG <path> element

Tags: css, svg

I am wandering how to draw a border-**right** to this svg square.

```html
<div>
  <svg>
    <path fill="rgba(199, 205, 217, 0.2)" d="M 154.5 10 L 154.5 399 L 407.5 399 L 407.5 10 Z" style="border: 1px solid red;"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

So it is not possible to use `stroke` nor `outline` as they draw a border all around the element (explained in this issue [SVG path with border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983531/svg-path-with-border)).

A constraint: I am not able to modify the SVG.

The best should be a css solution only. I don't know if it is feasible.

Comment: You could possible play with the stroke-dasharray/offset.

Answer (score 2):

You can put strokes where you want with stroke-dasharray.

If you want to know where the numbers are from they are just the side lengths of the shape.

```css
svg {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

path {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 642 389 253;
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg>
    <path fill="rgba(199, 205, 217, 0.2)" d="M 154.5 10 L 154.5 399 L 407.5 399 L 407.5 10 Z" ></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```