# SVG-graphics: cloudy border

Tags: javascript, svg

Is it possible to draw cloudy border for rect and polygon using svg-graphics? I tried using patterns in stroke, but it does not work.
I need border like this

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: you can use border image. Please take a look at this: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/1536b8683699125a03394937c0799ddb

Comment: Thank you, but I need set this type border for rect exactly, or for polygon. Not for div. Border property does not work for them.

Comment: In this case you will need a path element instead of rect and you'll have to draw the path yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fake it by using a dashed stroke with an SVG filter applied. Note this will likely slow down your page, so use the filter with caution.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 500" width="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
     <filter id="outline-sobel" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="0.3" result="BLUR" />
        <feConvolveMatrix in="BLUR" result="TOP-SOBEL" kernelMatrix="
         1  2  1  
         0  0  0  
        -1 -2 -1"/>
        <feConvolveMatrix in="BLUR" result="BOTTOM-SOBEL" kernelMatrix="
        -1 -2 -1  
         0  0  0  
         1  2  1"/>
        <feConvolveMatrix in="BLUR" result="LEFT-SOBEL" kernelMatrix="
         1  0 -1  
         2  0 -2  
         1  0 -1"/>
        <feConvolveMatrix in="BLUR" result="RIGHT-SOBEL" kernelMatrix="
        -1  0  1  
        -2  0  2  
        -1  0  1"/>
         
        <feComposite in="LEFT-SOBEL" in2="RIGHT-SOBEL" result="X" />
        <feComposite in="TOP-SOBEL" in2="BOTTOM-SOBEL" result="Y" />
        <feComposite in="X" in2="Y" />
    </filter>
    <style>
      .cb1{
          fill: none;
          stroke: tomato;
          stroke-width: 10;
        }
        .cb2{
          stroke-dasharray: 2 10;
        }
        .cb3{
          stroke-linecap: round;
          stroke-linejoin: round;
        }
        .cb4{
          fill: tomato;
        }
        .cb5
        {
            stroke-dasharray: 1 10 .9 10 1.1 10 .8 10 .7 10;
            stroke-dashoffset: 4;
            filter: url(#outline-sobel);
        }
        .cb6 {
            stroke-width: 5;
            stroke-dasharray: 0 5 0.1 5 0 5 ;
        }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="30" class="cb1" />
  <rect x="10" y="60" width="80" height="30" class="cb1 cb2" />
  <rect x="110" y="10" width="80" height="30" class="cb1 cb2 cb3" />
  <rect x="110" y="60" width="80" height="30" class="cb1 cb2 cb3 cb4" />
  <rect x="210" y="10" width="80" height="30" class="cb1 cb2 cb3 cb4 cb5" />
  <path d="
    M210 90 
    h80
    a 10 10 0 0 0 -12 -20
    a 18 18 0 0 0 -41 4
    a 13 13 0 0 0 -26 14
    z" 
    class="cb1 cb2 cb3 cb4 cb5 cb6" />
</svg>
```

Play with the values on the `stroke-dasharray` to get different effects, I've deliberately given a slightly random look.

Comment: Thank you very much. I need almost this, but without filling.

Comment: I'm pretty new to svg filters ... but that gives you a method without the filling now ... likely a more efficient way to achieve this, so good luck.